# Visual Studio 2017 Visual Basic - How to pass variable from one event to another

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I'm learning VS VB, so please forgive the ignorance.

I have built a form that accepts a file search pattern, searches for matching files and then displays the file names (up to 10) in text boxes.

If you double click on the file name (up to 10) text box, I want it to call a routine to open Powerpoint and display the first slide.

I've searched around and can't find any information thats helpful to me for 2017.

At this point, my code looks like below (just shows that I have the full file name).

```
Public Sub DisplaySong(ByVal SongFileName)

    Dim SongToDisplay As String = ""
    Dim i As Integer

    ' get the full song path/name
    Try
        Dim strFiles As String() = Directory.GetFiles(strSearchPath.ToString, SongFileName.ToString, IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories)
        i = 0
        ' should never be more than 1 song
        For Each SongFileName In strFiles
            SongToDisplay = strFiles(i)
            i = i + 1
        Next
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("Error processing Display Song: Finding Song!! ")
    End Try

    MessageBox.Show("Song Selected: " + SongToDisplay.ToString)

End Sub
```

The examples I've talk about adding the COMs, but I don't see "Microsoft Graph Object Library" in the 2017 version.  I selected MS PowerPoint and the MS Graph 14.0, thinking (hoping) that's what I needed.

When I add

```
Dim oApp as PowerPoint.Application
```

into the subroutine, I get the error message that it's not defined.  I know how to do this in Access VB 2010, but I don't know how to do this in VS VB 2017.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Dummy me.  Adding

```
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop
```

Fixed the problem.

Comment: You should improve this answer. Adding this line of code to the ones in your question does not magically make Powerpoint start doing anything. Your answer should include the changes made to the code in the question that (along with adding the reference) makes things work. As is, it's not a useful answer to the question you asked above.

Comment: That *is* the only change I made.  There were no changes to original included code.